Let's get critical: Jul 2015 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Paul Ekman suggests that in near-accidents, fear motivates people to hit their car brakes. Is the fear response fast enough to do this?

Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


How to test whether a person is Left-Eared or Right-Eared?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


Are there any free online questionnaire/survey sites that also measure the time it takes for participants to answer each question?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)


Applications and Limitations of EEG Electrode Pooling - Averaging across time series

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)


Brain's differences in introverts vs. extroverts

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)


What's the optimal type of exercise to increase BDNF

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)


Qualitative scoring for responses to design fluency task

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)


Analysis of RTs when speed-accuracy trade-off leading to ceiling accuracy has occurred

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)


Does motivation and interest correlate highly with IQ and can someone be smart but perform poorly in a particular field?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)


Anti-psychotic medication withdrawal-induced psychosis

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

